# Thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow'

Tags: memory, rust

I solved Project Euler #4 in Rust. There is one line of code that took me around 30 minutes to solve. When I remove the line, I get: thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow' Explanation is in the code:([see on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e8d8527d2bfef964086e36c01c5557b9))

The weird thing is, rev is 0, but when I try: rev=0; in the place that I have marked as 'problem here', it will solve the issue even though the value is same. Why is that? I have checked and this is not a duplicate question. I also didn't know what to write in the title since this is an uncommon error.

```
//Task: Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
    fn main(){   
        let mut pal;//palindrome
        let mut ram;//a second number that's equal to palindrome, to copy it's digits.
        let mut rev=0;//reversed palindrome
        let mut lar=0;//largest palindrome
        for ln in 100..1000{//ln=left number     }  left number * right number = palindrome
            for rn in 100..1000{//rn=right number}                                   ^
                pal=ln*rn;//                                                         |
                ram=pal;
                
                //-----------------Problem here-----------------
                //rev=ram%10;//when this line is commented, it gives:
                //thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow', why_overflow_pe4.rs:13:17
                
    
                while ram>0{//getting the last digit of ram for the first digit of rev
                            //and continuing until ram=0 and rev is reversed.
                    rev*=10;
                    ram/=10;
                    rev+=ram%10;
                }
                rev/=10;
                if pal==rev && pal>lar{//if rev=pal and our palindrome is larger than previous largest
                                      //make the largest palindrome current palindrome
                    lar=pal;
                }
            }
        }
        println!("{}",lar);
    }
```

-Thank you!

Comment: Note that `rev` is zero on your problem line _only for the first iteration._ Ie. only when `ln == 100` and `rn == 100`. Afterwards `rev` keeps whatever value it had at the end of the previous iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Inspecting the contents before the multiplication](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7baac23ed376066db53fe210e56ab198) of `rev` may help: `rev` has the value 1010102010, and multiplying it by 10 would result in a number that is too large (i.e. would require too many bits) to be held by `rev`.

If you uncomment the `rev=ram%10`, `rev` will surely be less than 10, so multiplying it by 10 results in at most 100.

You can specify the data type size using `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64`, `u128` et al., but even `u128` will overflow. Thus, you could either adapt your algorithm or go with a data type supporting more than 128 bits.

Comment: I didn't understand this part: "If you uncomment the rev=ram%10, rev will surely be less than 10, so multiplying it by 10 results in at most 100.", isn't rev less than 10?, when is it stops being 0 and becomes a large number? I mean it's value is already at 0, then I should get the same error when I write rev=0; in the place of comment. Why is it not happening?

Comment: `ram%10` computes `ram` modulo 10, which is the remainder of `ram` divided by 10. The remainder of a division must be smaller than the divisor (which is 10 in this case).

Comment: Yeah but, the thing I mean is here, run it in your machine. The browser is not showing anything to me: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4c51793c7e20598e0b5b9a75e802cee

Comment: I think your assumption that `rev` is 0 is wrong: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae2cb76815e951a81f0b523d19ea4dac. (It is not reset to 0 in the loop, only at the beginning.)

Comment: I've been in similar situations, and the `dbg!` macro helped me tremendously.