# Rust-lang thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow' when .collect with usize type

Tags: rust

What I do:
I try change `.collect::<Vec<(i32, i32)>>();` to `.collect::<Vec<(usize, usize)>>();`

```rust
    let result = (0..4)
        .flat_map(|x| {
            (0..=x - 1).map(move |y| {
                println!("{:?},{:?}", y, x);
                (y, x)
            })
        })
        .collect::<Vec<(usize, usize)>>();
    assert_eq!(usize::BITS, 64);
```

Expected:
The program should print this output

```
0,1
0,2
1,2
0,3
1,3
2,3
```

Reality:
Causing this error

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', sandbox.rs:4:18
stack backtrace:
   0:        0x104e5b714 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::h3cae2b905fd8ac13
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:93:5
   1:        0x104e5b714 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::he35fb4c47e25f88c
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
   2:        0x104e5b714 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::hdb42afc2298dc41a
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:66:5
   3:        0x104e5b714 - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::hc80096156cd24709
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:45:22
   4:        0x104e6f36b - core::fmt::write::hb6b947db0e571766
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1194:17
   5:        0x104e59998 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h59c4febf5f8fcb1e
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1655:15
   6:        0x104e5ceed - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h72a3180302df7468
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:48:5
   7:        0x104e5ceed - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::ha0747cec3f48ad89
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:35:9
   8:        0x104e5ceed - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h0e76f92bbb367061
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:295:22
   9:        0x104e5cbd1 - std::panicking::default_hook::hbbbb8c05ad6cce9a
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:314:9
  10:        0x104e5d46e - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::ha581a2c99399f83b
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:698:17
  11:        0x104e5d32a - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::h97df6e4273b6a879
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:586:13
  12:        0x104e5bb97 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::ha4a3b48ae6bfb343
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:138:18
  13:        0x104e5d03a - rust_begin_unwind
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
  14:        0x104e75ad3 - core::panicking::panic_fmt::h4a5343602e6cbb54
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/core/src/panicking.rs:143:14
  15:        0x104e759b7 - core::panicking::panic::h6b179fc6a750c6a7
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/core/src/panicking.rs:48:5
  16:        0x104e3b9be - sandbox::main::{{closure}}::hf08783165a52a79c
  17:        0x104e3b80c - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &mut F>::call_once::hf882f89c41f0bc1a
  18:        0x104e3db0a - core::option::Option<T>::map::h8da6a8ee39a64700
  19:        0x104e3b76d - <core::iter::adapters::map::Map<I,F> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next::hff3dfbd45c29371a
  20:        0x104e3bead - <core::iter::adapters::fuse::Fuse<I> as core::iter::adapters::fuse::FuseImpl<I>>::next::hc0f3bee62dae5fb7
  21:        0x104e3bdf4 - <core::iter::adapters::fuse::Fuse<I> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next::h5e78846a93a83854
  22:        0x104e3a9b1 - <core::iter::adapters::flatten::FlattenCompat<I,U> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next::h4e729994babe33d0
  23:        0x104e3a914 - <core::iter::adapters::flatten::FlatMap<I,U,F> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next::hc25c9d268b91673b
  24:        0x104e3cff8 - <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as alloc::vec::spec_from_iter_nested::SpecFromIterNested<T,I>>::from_iter::hc317abd23254384d
  25:        0x104e3d5bb - <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as alloc::vec::spec_from_iter::SpecFromIter<T,I>>::from_iter::h83bc07655110a239
  26:        0x104e3d54a - <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as core::iter::traits::collect::FromIterator<T>>::from_iter::h97531d9802a79ec6
  27:        0x104e3b24b - core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator::collect::h7d66f1c588b4ccd5
  28:        0x104e3b93c - sandbox::main::h665c6f01c25b7779
  29:        0x104e3b5ca - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h66b82387820b635c
  30:        0x104e3b39d - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h69deb9d52437a77b
  31:        0x104e3e1d0 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h7e1e8999ed160d7b
  32:        0x104e568ba - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once::h45b43bdd91db95dd
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:259:13
  33:        0x104e568ba - std::panicking::try::do_call::h249f439f16aa313c
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:492:40
  34:        0x104e568ba - std::panicking::try::ha8537a1873fa2ff9
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:456:19
  35:        0x104e568ba - std::panic::catch_unwind::hffa61ccaeb4f89c5
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
  36:        0x104e568ba - std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}::h32bbf4c39987b002
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:48
  37:        0x104e568ba - std::panicking::try::do_call::h558936e01b59417c
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:492:40
  38:        0x104e568ba - std::panicking::try::h12a630e8ced1b46a
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panicking.rs:456:19
  39:        0x104e568ba - std::panic::catch_unwind::h539ca15d1ec773ea
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
  40:        0x104e568ba - std::rt::lang_start_internal::hdb19fe6764e59ca8
                               at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:20
  41:        0x104e3e1b2 - std::rt::lang_start::h779bf72e0eff05a1
  42:        0x104e3bab6 - _main
```

My environment `Darwin xxx.local 21.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:22 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Question:
`usize` in my machine is 64 so I expect changing from `i32` to `usize` should be valid

1. Is this an issue with overflow or the error are just generic?
2. If the issue is not related to overflow then why I can't use `usize`

Context:
The reason I use `.collect::<Vec<(usize, usize)>>();` is because this error in another code here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be45ed1d9d5cd836a37040da20243b26

Code: snippet code that causes the error
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6929e4620c980749397de4c1b5f03a03

Similar issue:
There seems to be a similar error on StackOverflow here
[thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407558/thread-main-panicked-at-attempt-to-subtract-with-overflow)
[Thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647958/thread-main-panicked-at-attempt-to-multiply-with-overflow)
[Panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow' when cycling backwards though a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301485/panicked-at-attempt-to-subtract-with-overflow-when-cycling-backwards-though-a)
https://discord.com/channels/442252698964721669/448238009733742612/975126106090921994
But all of them are arithmetic operations related which I don't think is the case with my code.

Comment: I like your post but this is a very simple misunderstanding. If `x` is a `usize` (since it is being collected as such) and your iterations start with 0, then trying to do `x - 1` will overflow.

Comment: The actual misunderstanding here I think is that `a..b` includes `a` but does **not** include `b`. To include `b`, you would have to write `a..=b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum value of `usize` is 0 and you're computing `0 - 1` in the first iteration in the expression `(0..=x - 1)` which causes an underflow.

You probably want to use `(0..x)` which creates a range upto `x - 1` but does not cause an underflow if `x == 0` (it simply creates an empty range):

```
let result = (0..4)
    .flat_map(|x| {
        (0..x).map(move |y| {
            println!("{:?},{:?}", y, x);
            (y, x)
        })
    })
    .collect::<Vec<(usize, usize)>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b67f5116d7fad192f0331f21e0901f77)